# Yum doesn't recognize installed dependency version

Tags: centos, centos7, yum

I'm trying to install `gcc-c++` on CentOS 7.6.1810. This is the error output:

```
Error: Package: glibc-2.17-260.el7.i686 (centos_7_x64_32)
   Requires: glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7
   Installed: glibc-common-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64 (@updates)
       glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7_6.3
   (cut)
   Available: glibc-common-2.17-260.el7.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
       glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7
```

It seems that `yum` doesn't recognize `glibc-common-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64` as the same as (or equivalent of) `glibc-common-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64`. What can I do to tell it to honor this installed version, or how can I reinstall it from `centos_7_x64_32` (obviously I can't remove glibc-common first).

## FULL OUTPUT

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.8.5-36.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gcc = 4.8.5-36.el7 for package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++-devel = 4.8.5-36.el7 for package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpc.so.3()(64bit) for package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpfr.so.4()(64bit) for package: gcc-c++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.8.5-36.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: cpp = 4.8.5-36.el7 for package: gcc-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 for package: gcc-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
---> Package libmpc.x86_64 0:1.0.1-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.8.5-36.el7 will be installed
---> Package mpfr.x86_64 0:3.1.1-4.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.8.5-36.el7 will be installed
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.17-260.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.17-260.el7 for package: glibc-devel-2.17-260.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.17-260.el7 for package: glibc-devel-2.17-260.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers for package: glibc-devel-2.17-260.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.17-260.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7 for package: glibc-2.17-260.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.17-260.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.17-260.el7.i686
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-260.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1 for package: glibc-headers-2.17-260.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers for package: glibc-headers-2.17-260.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.17-260.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7 for package: glibc-2.17-260.el7.i686
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-957.1.3.el7 will be installed
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.36.0-5.el7_5 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.17-260.el7.i686 (centos_7_x64_32)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7
           Installed: glibc-common-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64 (@updates)
               glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7_6.3
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-78.el7.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-78.el7
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-105.el7.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-105.el7
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.1.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.1
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.4
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.6
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.8
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-157.el7.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-157.el7
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-157.el7_3.1
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.2.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-157.el7_3.2
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.4.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-157.el7_3.4
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.5.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-157.el7_3.5
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-196.el7.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7_4.2
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-222.el7.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-222.el7
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-260.el7.x86_64 (centos_7_x64_32)
               glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Looks like the private mirror you are using is incomplete. Go have a chat with whoever maintains it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I had similar problem before with not so important package. The required dependency was installed from `@updates` with some "_x.y" version suffix and yum didn't like it. I had to uninstall it, and install the same version from `centos_7_x64_32`, but without the suffix. Then it worked ok. I can't do that with `glibc-common`.

Comment: Again, you aren't using an official CentOS repository to obtain base packages. You can either yell at whoever maintains your private copy of the repository, or switch back to the official repository (if your company even allows this).

Answer (score 2):

> Error: Package: glibc-2.17-260.el7.**i686**
>   (My emphasis)

you are trying to install the i686 variant not the x86_64 variant. You need to meet the i686 requirements or install the x86_64 package.

Comment: `yum install gcc-c++.x86_64` renders the same error and `glibc-2.17-260.el7.x86_64` is already installed. Why does it want to install `i686` variant?

Comment: Because you installed it I guess.

Comment: @lain I won't pretend that I understand you. What did I install? God, I hate CentOS;)

Comment: Like you, I have no idea how your system got to be in such a state.

Answer (score -1):

Somehow, you do not have the "updates" repo available. You either disabled it or you are using a private repo/mirror that does not has it.